# Passing String from FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am able to get String in FragmentActivity from Activity. However, how do I pass on my data from FragmentActivity to Fragments? I am able to get my data in FragmentActivity though.

(I do not want to store data in SharedPreferences.)

```
public class IndividualDetailsActivity extends IndividualBasePager {

    ViewPager mPager;
    IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter mAdapter;
    TitlePageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.individual_pager);
        mAdapter = new IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        mIndicator.setCurrentItem(1);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(i.getStringExtra("name"));
    }
}

public class IndividualBasePager extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


public class IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Comments",
            "Details", "Screens", "Tutorial" };

    private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

    public IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.e("PAGE", "Position " + position);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new CommentsFragment();
        case 1:
            return new DetailsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new CommentsFragment();
        case 3:
            return new CommentsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment you can get the FragmentActivity by calling the following method `getActivity()` . And In your FragmentActivity create a method like `getValue()` which will return you the required data.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation recommends that you use the parent activity of the fragment.  You should not use fragment to fragment communication, so that you can reuse the fragment in other places, if necessary and keeping it reuseable.  Having said that, I would suggest using Extras that are placed on the bundle.

You put things like this:

```
savedInstanceState.putString("myString", myStingVariable);
```

and you can get them like this:

```
myStingVariable = savedInstanceState.getString("myString");
```

You will also want to check that the value isn't null.

Note that there are different getters and setters for different types of variables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setter method in you fragment as below. And from your activity, just call that method.

```
public class IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Comments",
        "Details", "Screens", "Tutorial" };

private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

private String name;
public void setName(String name)
{
  this.name=name;
}


public IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
 ... // Rest of your stuff.
 }
```

You can call the setName method from your Activity as below,

```
mAdapter = new IndividualDetailsBaseAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mAdapter.setName(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
```